# "(" char doesn't work in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I can't get this to work. It doesn't like the "(" char;

how do I fix it?

```
 Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "(","" }
```

How do I handle this type of special character in PowerShell?

Comment: I have no experience with `powershell`, since like most other users here I work on Linux and use a standard shell like `bash` instead. But this should be the same in all environments: you have to "escape" special characters which have control meaning otherwise. So look for how to escape characters in powershell, most likely it is something like the `backslash`: `Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "\(","" }`. But then again: MS always does things in another way if something is typical, so it might well be another character you need to use. Check the documentation.

Comment: @arkascha Please tune down the unprofessional anti-MS attitude. It doesn't really help answering the question, as .Net indeed uses `\` for escape char in regex.

Comment: @vonPryz I do not see what the problem is: this was no "attitude" or anything. I gave a hint how this is _usually_ done (read: in other shells), and added a hint that this might be slightly different in an MS environment (which you confirmed). So it _does_ help, since it points out the right path.

Comment: @arkascha it really only helps by chance. The escape character in Powershell is back-quote. In this case you need a backslash to escape the special character inside a regular expression not because the shell syntax needs any escaping. If you look at the answer I gave you'll see that it actually possible to do the replacement without escaping the `(`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've got a great explanation of the exact cause of your problem from @vonPryze, but there's a much simpler solution. The `-replace` operator uses regular expressions which need escaping, but the `.Replace()` string method just uses strings. So if you don't need a regex, just use the method and there's no need to escape anything:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName { $_.name.Replace("(","") }
```

Comment: Also, I think it should be mentioned, the `Replace` method is case sensitive, but a bit faster than the `-Replace` operator.

Answer (score 9):

Let's try analyzing the problem a bit. First off, create some dummy files that contain a parenthesis like so,

```
for($i=0;$i -le 4; ++$i) { set-content -path $("file($i).txt" -f $i) -value $i }
Output:
gci
    Directory: C:\temp\foo
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file(0).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file(1).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file(2).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file(3).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file(4).txt
```

Now that we have some test data, let's try to run the command that provied an error message like so,

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "(","" }

Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed.
Invalid regular expression pattern: (.
At line:1 char:27
+ Dir | Rename-Item -NewName <<<<  { $_.name -replace "(","" }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (file(0).txt:PSObject) [Rename-Item], ParameterBind   ingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptBlockArgumentInvocationFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Re   nameItemCommand
```

Oops! The error message says that *an invalid regular expression* was used. That means `-replace` is not going to just replace strings but it supports [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) too!

In order to get `-replace` to treat the input as literal text instead of a regex, the input needs to be escaped. The simple way is to insert backslashes `\`, but this gets soon tedious. There luckily is an easier way, as .Net Regex class has a built-in escape method `[Regex]::Excape()`. Like so,

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace [regex]::escape("("),"" }
Output:
ls
    Directory: C:\temp\foo
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file0).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file1).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file2).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file3).txt
-a---         17.2.2014     10:34          3 file4).txt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace "\(","" } # This works
```